# Find the difference of Employee and manager salaries using MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

I have a Dimension with attributes Employee Number, Manager Number. Measure called Salary.

I need to display employee number , his/her Manager number and Salary difference.

sample data like below.

EmpNo - ManagerNo - Salary 
1 - 0 - 10000 
2 - 1 - 8000 
3 - 2 - 7000 
4- 0 - 12000

expected output as 
EmpNo-ManagerNo-Diff.in Salary 
1 - Not available - 10000 
2- 1 - 2000 
3 - 2 - 1000 
4 - Not available - 12000

If no manager means we can show same salary.
Could you please guide me how to achieve this using MDX.

Thank you for any support.